# iOS static table auto resize based on textView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, autolayout, tableview

I have Text views inside a static table. I want them to resize when there is need for a line break. How do i do this? This is my code so far.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    table.estimatedRowHeight = 40.0 // Replace with your actual estimation
    table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension


    // Tap to dismiss keyboard
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(EditInfoViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


}


func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
    // Save data
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Swift 3 & Xcode 8.3.2**

Use UILabel instead of UITextView, and set numberOfLine = 0, so it will automatic resize according to its content

or

if you want to keep UITextView instead UILabel, here is the code

```
class YourClass: UITableViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    var yourCustomCell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        table.estimatedRowHeight = 40.0 // Replace with your actual estimation
        table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension


        // Tap to dismiss keyboard
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(EditInfoViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        // Add tableView delegate
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        // Add textView delegate
        yourTextView.delegate = self


    }
    // Text view delegate, dont forget to add yourTextView.delegate = self in viewDidLoad
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView == yourTextView {
            let newHeight = yourCustomCell.frame.size.height + textView.contentSize.height
            yourCustomCell.frame.size.height = newHeight
            updateTableViewContentOffsetForTextView()
        }
    }
    // Animate cell, the cell frame will follow textView content
    func updateTableViewContentOffsetForTextView() {
        let currentOffset = tableView.contentOffset
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
        tableView.setContentOffset(currentOffset, animated: false)
    }


    // UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }



    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = yourCustomCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
}
```

The result is here:
[image: Before the code]

Result after using textViewDelegate, and custom resizing function
[image: After the code]

Comment: I don't know how to make a label edditable so I went for making the textView resize. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. This is how I set the textView's delegate:    

titleTextView.delegate = self as? UITextViewDelegate

Comment: @Ideaman in your viewDidLoad declare this "titleTextView.deleget = self", and in yourClass add this Class myViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {}

Comment: It wants me to cast it to UITextViewDelegate

Comment: Oh I see, still does not work though. Is there anything else you have done?

Comment: @alvarlagerlof this is my last edited answer, if still not work for you, please show more code, so i can fix it for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145231/discussion-between-alvarlagerlof-and-andrian-yohanes).

Comment: In this example its dynamic, not static table view. And answer does not work for static table view altogether.

Comment: @Granfalloner see again the code before downvote, it’s clearly worked for dynamic and static, but that example is programmatic approach

Comment: @AndrianRahardja, the exact reason why I downvoted your answer is that it doesn't work. And I surely tested it. It works for table view with dynamic cells, thats right. But the question was specifically about table view with static cells. I don't know why do you suppose that it should work for table view with static cells if it worked for table view with dynamic cells - and in fact, this assumption is not correct, you can check yourself. Thus your answer is misleading. Please correct it to reflect that it works only for dynamic table view - in that case, I'll upvote.